# How many web users be unable to use my app if I used HTML 5?

Tags: html

I was looking at a wiki page on HTML5 support and left it feeling a little confused. Here's the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29)

If I understand it, then IE has near to no support and the others have between a little and some. none have lots.

So HTML 5 incorporates a load of different technologies, some closer to completion than others. So let's focus on say Canvas and drag and drop and anything else you think would make sense, Video tag? You choose.

I'm also not sure what has changed in Javascript. I assume there are new APIs for things like Canvas?

Would a significant segment of web users be unable to use my site if I only used HTML5, especially the fun stuff, Canvas, etc?

Comment: The are many good resources for this, http://html5please.com/ http://caniuse.com/ among others

Comment: If we relay on the information published on Smashing Magazine here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/09/old-browsers-are-holding-back-the-web/ we have pretty good chance that the html5 propagation is going to be higher as ie<9 users are going to migrate to new modern web browsers on which the canvas support is pretty solid. Anyway there is an exception again in the person of Internet Explorer, which does not support WebGL.

Comment: Interesting resources, especially yours esimov.

Comment: Well, IE will always be years behind all the other browsers when it comes to supporting modern standards and practices, not just WebGL.

Comment: IE is an interesting one given Microsoft's HTML5 based strategy. It's actually part of what prompted me to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All current browsers support HTML5. Just how much and how well it supports HTML5 is in question, hence the helpful links others have posted. However you need to be cautious because a browser may claim support but does so poorly or incompletely. `<audio` works great in every browser but IE if you want to use the preload attribute. The 'contenteditable' attribute is wonderful but, if the user hits the return key, you get different results.

Simple examples but something to think about. Eventually it will all sort out.

In any case, we use HTML5 technologies wherever we can because eventually everyone will. They're very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more friendly html5 browser compatability chart: https://html5test.com/results/desktop.html.

Then you need to look at your site's traffic analytics and see what percentage of your visitors use html5 compatible browsers.

Comment: I'd need traffic before I could analyse any meaningful percentage of the internet. Excellent resource though, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unanswerable, because different browsers implement different features of HTML5. You have to look at each HTML5 / CSS3 feature you want to use specifically and look at sites such as caniuse.com, where it will tell how what % of global users can support it.

You should already be using HTML5 doctype tags, and any other more semantic HTML5 elements that all browsers will render.

Comment: Look I'm not looking for a numerically precise answer, I'm not going to castigate anyone who is more than .5pc out. I started from the position that the standard is in flux with variable levels of adoption. I even listed a few parts which I would include.